# Querying dynamic Search Results and sending specific search object to a details jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp, servlets

I'm currently working on a assignment that basically does a search for restaurants and I am currently looping through my search results to display them and I want the user to be able to click on the image of a specific restaurant and be redirected to the details page for that restaurant. I currently am doing:

```
<div id="query">
                    <%
                    for(int i=0; i<results.size(); i++)
                    {
                        Restaurant result = results.get(i);
                    %>
                        <div class="restaurants">
                         <%request.getSession().setAttribute("result", results.get(i)); %> 
                             <a href="detailsPage.jsp">
                                <img src= "<%=result.getImage()%>" id="imageChange">
                            </a>
                            <div class="restaurantInfo">
                                <p style="font-size: 27px; color: rgb(94, 93, 93);"><%=result.getRestaurantName()%></p>
                                <p style="font-size: 25px; color: rgb(122, 122, 122);"><%=result.getAddress()%></p>
                                <p style="font-size: 25px; color: rgb(94, 93, 93);"> <%=result.getLink()%></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <%}; %>
```

And just use the getAttribute() method in the details page jsp to get the 'result' object that I send. Only problem is that it gets the last Restaurant object that I set and I'm certain that it's because the setAttribute() is getting overridden at iteration by ith restaurant object. So, how do I go about sending the right object? Please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `restautantId` to detail.jsp URL parameter as

```
 <a href="detailsPage.jsp?restaurantId=<%=result.getId()%>">
     <img src= "<%=result.getImage()%>" id="imageChange">
</a>
```

In your servlet, you can get restautantId by

```
request.getParameter("restautantId");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Do I need to create a details servlet and pass in my ArrayList to send it to the jsp? I currently don't have a getId() method as all my objects are just regular java objects.

Comment: your result query should return restaurantId too

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, I currently am not using SQL. I'm doing search using the yelp api and creating restaurant objects from the data I parsed from the api and then putting them into an ArrayList. That's what I send to my SearchResults jsp and display in my code above.

Comment: to go to detail page, you need have unique field to get detail infor, may be restaurant name or address?